# Reasonable Git repo(s) schema?

Tags: git

We have a current Subversion repository that looks similar in structure to:

```
/Core
    Shared_dll_projects/
        In here we have a few C# projects that compile to DLLs which are used by all the customer's projects

    Web/
        customer_1/
            trunk/
            branches/
                releases/
                    v1/
                    v2/
                    v3
                
        customer_2/
            trunk/
            branches/
                releases/
                    v1.1/
                    v1.2/
                
        customer_3/

        etc
```

The repository is private to the company I work for; our customers have no access to it. It's unlikely that this will ever change.

Recently we've toyed with switching to Git. I wonder if the the above repository schema might be reasonable for Git? Is it better to have 1 repo per customer?

Note: In our case we, from time to time, merge from one branch in one customer to a branch in a different customer. Each customer is about 80% similar to the next.

Comment: Git isn't a substitute for an artifact store or dependency management.  It sounds like you have common functionality you want to share between customers but you lack some way to do it, so for now you use Subversion to manage it.  That...feels like a headache.

Comment: @Makoto Those shared resources are C# code that we write and actively manage. They're not just binaries. They need versioning just as much as the customer's code.

Comment: ...which is why it's a good idea to use an artifact store to publish those, and use dependency management to pull them in, all while that code safely and securely lives inside of its own repository with its own regression tests.  Ostensibly, this isn't a Git problem, or a problem that Git is engineered to solve particularly well (I mean I know that submodules exist but I wouldn't recommend them here.)

Comment: @Makoto Ignoring the code that compiles to DLLs (which really could just be C# projects that are included in the C# web solutions), is it better to have 1 repo per customer even though we sometimes merge between customers?

Comment: Can't say "better" since there's no objective answer on what's better.  Different things work for different organizations.  I'm only volunteering that this isn't something that Git can actually "solve".

Comment: @Makoto Why use an artifact store for the C# that compiles to DLLs? It's just more code, why is it better to treat shared code differently than the code which uses it?

Comment: The DLLs are build artifacts, not source code.

Comment: @torek But we don't store the compiled DLL, we store our source code (C#) which we compile to create the DLLs as needed. The DLLs are wrote by us, we maintain the source code for them.

Comment: Yes, and then the built DLLs are build artifacts, which go into an artifactory (a place from which one can retrieve built artifacts, but not manage source files as the source files are elsewhere). The artifactory can literally just be a caching server that rebuilds the DLLs on demand, provided you have reproducible builds.